# Red Question Marks in Acrobat PDF Reader

Tags: pdf, jabref, acrobat

I updated my JabRef to the latest version (5.2) and installed some fonts yesterday. After that, every citation (maybe as well as every "\ref") is labeled with a red question mark when I try to open a normal pdf file with the Acrobat pdf reader.

Please see a snapshot of this bug:
[image: pdf]

Foxit pdf reader works well on the same pdf file. Other pdf files have the same question with the Acrobat pdf reader. The red question marks cannot be clicked or edited. Thus, I cannot figure out why this happens.

Please help because I can't find the answer anywhere. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is impossible to help if you don't show any code. Try to make  a small but complete example which demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Sorry for the unclarity. Since the PDF file (as well as other tested pdf files) was directly downloaded from the IEEE Xplore (not produced by myself), there is no Tex code for troubleshooting. Adobe acrobat pdf reader worked well on these pdf files before I updated the JabRef to 5.2. It seems that there are some problems in the collaboration between Adobe acrobat pdf reader and the newest version of JabRef.

Comment: do you have public link for a (short) pdf with this problem?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer This problem is repeatedly found on all my pdf files (downloaded from various websites). In addition, the Foxit pdf reader still works well on the same pdf files. Thus, I am pretty sure pdf files are not the reason.

Comment: Then this issue seems to be related to the fonts you installed and is not related to JabRef or Tex. Maybe you uninstalled some existing fonts or have overwritten some existing ones and Acrobat picked these up. This seems like the only plausible reason.

Comment: @Christoph S I have uninstalled those fonts. This problem is solved, thanks！

Comment: @xueyinhualuo I am willing to try. But I'm not willing to spent my time trying out arbitrary pdf files. So either you provide the info or I do something else. You should also tell which OS you are using.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thank you for all your help! I have uninstalled those fonts, updated the acrobat, and rebooted my win10. Then, the problem is solved!